Best ways to distribute a .ppam file
I have a VBA PowerPoint add-in (.ppam file) that works fine. It's based on a .pptm file, and it adds a new tab into the PowerPoint ribbon (no task pane). This new tab was customized using RibbonX Editor.
Now I would like to distribute it to over 100 people, working on PCs only (no mac).
Here are the two options I have considered so far:

Asking everyone to download the .ppam file, then install the add-in from "PowerPoint" - "Options".
It requires a dozen clicks, it is far from being user-friendly, and .ppam files downloads can be blocked by some antivirus

Building a .exe file that would automatically install the add-in, using a Powershell script that edits the HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint etc.
The user experience is much better, but download and installation may fail depending on user's admin rights and security settings. Also, setting up an identity and getting a signing certificate from Microsoft (so that the .exe file is properly signed) sounds like a long and painful process when you work as a freelancer


What would be the best alternatives? For instance, could it be done from the Microsoft 365 Apps admin center (for all of the users working at a given company)? and if so:

how can I generate the required manifest file (which I suppose is necessary)?
do i need to redevelop everything using a solution such as Visual Studio?


A lot will depend on the IT people you have to work with in the target company.
If you also work there and they trust you/your addin, they probably can push it out to all users or a subset, set the necessary registry entries, etc, all with admin privileges.
If they require all addins to be signed, it might be enough for them to use a self-signing certificate. If a full cert is required, check with them to see what sort of cert they insist on. There are probably easier and possibly less expensive ways of getting one than through MS.  Comodo is a commonly used one:
https://ssl.comodoca.com/code-signing-certificate
